# Neo4j 3.0 - Unable to fetch data from older version (2.3.2) database

Tags: neo4j

My older database version is 2.3.2. There I created a database and inserted nodes and relationships.

Now, I upgraded to 3.0 version and restarted the neo4j server. Changed the
`dbms.active_directory = xyz_path`

But unable to fetch the data from the db now.

Is there any more configurations or any specific changes I need to do to access the database.

**Edited**
Error while using migrating the config files:

```
[root@enteras02 tools]# java -jar config-migrator.jar path/to/neo4j2.3 path/to/neo4j3.0
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/neo4j/config/ConfigMigrator : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)

Comment: actually neo4j should fail to start ? Is it starting. There is another setting : `dbms.allow_format_migration=true` and the documentation reference for upgrading : http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/#upgrading

Comment: No Luck @ChristopheWillemsen

Comment: is your database starting ?

Comment: do you have something in the logs ?

Comment: did you do a clean shutdown on 2.3.x ? Otherwise store upgrade potentially does not work.

Comment: Database is zipped and transferred to new machine with 3.0 neo4j version. Here I configured to the data location in the conf files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `dbms.active_database` (NOT `dbms.active_directory`, which is not documented) is supposed to be the **name** of the database directory (not a path) under your `$NEO4J_HOME/data/databases/` directory. For example: "my_old_graph.db".

So, move your old database under the `$NEO4J_HOME/data/databases/` directory, and set `dbms.active_database` to its name.

In addition, as @ChristopheWillemsen said, you also have to set `dbms.allow_format_migration=true` to tell neo4j to upgrade to new major version.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an older Java version installed.
If you have version 7 and 8 installed you should uninstall version 7.